# Is gelilah like getting all the aliyah

Tags: hagbah-gelilah

when I was younger one of my rabbi's told be that gelilah is like u get all the aliyah. I am wondering what the source on this if this is true?

Answer (score 9):

The source he referenced is seemingly from Megillah 32a:

> ואמר ר' שפטיה א"ר יוחנן עשרה שקראו בתורה הגדול שבהם גולל ספר תורה הגוללו נוטל שכר כולן דאמר ר' יהושע בן לוי עשרה שקראו בתורה הגולל ספר תורה קיבל שכר כולן שכר כולן סלקא דעתך אלא אימא קיבל שכר כנגד כולן
> Rav Shefatya said that Rabbi Yochanan said: 10 who read from the Torah, the greatest among them rolls the Torah; the roller takes all their rewards, for Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said "10 who read from the Torah, the one who rolls the Torah receives all their rewards". Could it really mean all their rewards? Rather say it means: he receives rewards equivalent to all of theirs.